# Freeing all allocated memory in case of failure

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

I'm working on a C project (assignment for school).  One of the demands is that in case of `malloc()` failure, the program must `free()` all allocated memory and `exit()`.

Consider a case where function `A()` constructs a linked-list and in each iteration it calls to another function, `B()`. Now, if a malloc failure occured at `B()`, it must `free()` the memory it allocated but function `A()` should do that as well.

Things are getting quite complicated when you have a tree of function calls larger than two.

In my previous project I used a flag to notify a malloc() failure - if a function uses another function which may use `malloc()`, it has to check the flag right after.  It worked, but code got kinda messy.

Is there a neat solution for this problem?
Of course, with "real" applications all memory is de-allocated by the OS, but I guess this demand is pedagogical..

Comment: Are you looking for a pseudo-code type answer?

Comment: Not at all. I am asking for an approach\ idea.

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting those downvotes.

Comment: Return success/failure value from each function, but `exit` only on the top level.

Comment: The downvotes are because it's not quite clear what exactly you want as an answer.

Comment: I up-voted, because all you want is idea. So please add your comment "Not at all. I am asking for an approach\ idea" in question to not get more down votes.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest approach is to create a custom allocator (as somebody already noted in a deleted post) to keep track of all your allocations, then do a custom deallocator, use these for all your heap memory needs.

if a malloc fails you have the list of previously allocated blocks at easy reach.

e.g. 
(you need to redo this cause it is not effective and should be optimized but shows the principle and only ocular compilation)

```
typedef struct
{
  void* pMemory; /* for the allocated memory */
  size_t size;   /* for better debugging */

} MemoryBlock;

#define MAXBLOCKS 1000

MemoryBlock myheap[MAXBLOCKS]; // global so zero:ed
static int block = 0;

void* myalloc(size_t size)
{
   static int block = 0;

   // you should check vs MAXBLOCKS 

   myheap[block].pMemory = malloc(size); 
   myheap[block].size = size;   

   // check if it failed.
   if ( myheap[block].pMemory == NULL )
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < block; ++i)
      {
         myfree(myheap[i].pMemory);
      }
      fprintf( stderr, "out of memory\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else
   {
     return myheap[block++].pMemory;
   }
}

void myfree(void* p)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < block; ++i)
   {
      if ( p == myheap[i].pMemory )
      {
         free(myheap[i].pMemory);
         myheap[i].pMemory = NULL;
         return; 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Lots of debugging aids keep track of the allocation and de-allocation and then able to provide a leak report at the end or following any 'conservative' processing (that should net nil allocate). They usually end up with a linked list or hash-table under the hood rather than an array. But for a novice exercise I would be OK with this. In short, looping through the allocated heap to find the item being `free`ed will be unacceptably slow in almost any practical application.

Comment: @DanAllen yes of course its not effective, but my intention was not to solve his school assignment, just point him in one direction

Comment: I know, My comments aren't intended as critcism. I was just pointing where your 'toy' solution runs out.

Comment: the downside with this solution is that you are limited to a fixed amount of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The best (and conventional) way is to initialize every pointer value to zero.  Then set it during the malloc() assignment.  Ex:  myPtr = malloc( 10 );

It will be zero in case of failure, and you check that.  And finally, when you go about freeing, you always check the pointer value before calling free():

```
if ( myPtr != 0 )
    free( myPtr );
```

There is no need for an extra flag.

Comment: there is no need to check pointer before freeing, if it is null nothing happens

Comment: Not all implementations are that reliable, embedded libraries in particular.

Comment: its according to the C standard. if it is not implemented it is a bug in the compiler. it would otherwise break tons of legacy code

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the `atexit()` function, to register code that will be executed when the program terminates. Such code can then check if there is anything that needs to be `free()`d.

Note that `atexit()` has no way to unregister. So you need to make sure that you register each cleanup function only once, and that it does the right thing when there is nothing to clean up.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *ptr1;
char *ptr2;
int clean1_registered, clean2_registered;

void clean1(void)
{
    printf("clean1 called\n");
    if (ptr1) {
        free(ptr1);
        ptr1 = NULL;
    }
}

void clean2(void)
{
    printf("clean2 called\n");
    if (ptr2) {
        free(ptr2);
        ptr2 = NULL;
    }
}

void B(void)
{
    ptr2 = malloc(100);
    if (!clean2_registered) {
        atexit(clean2);
    }
}

void A(void)
{
    ptr1 = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
    if (!clean1_registered) {
        atexit(clean1);
    }
    B();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you having issue checking for errors or handling them? If you want info on catching them, use donjuedo's suggestion.

For ideas on freeing memory in the event of error, try one of these two methods:

1) For a uni-directional linked-list, keep a special pointer that points to the head of the list. In your cascading free function, start at the head, capture the next-pointer in a temp variable, free the head, move to the next structure in the list using the temp-pointer, and repeat the process until the next-pointer == 0.

2) For a bi-directional linked-list (my preference) you don't need to keep a special pointer to the head of the list. Assuming you are still at the tail, just capture the previous-pointer into a temp variable, free the tail, move back using the temp-pointer, and repeat the process until the previous-pointer == 0